# finding out Gerrit server version when having URL

Tags: gerrit

What's the most reliable way of finding out what's the version of a Gerrit server if the only thing I have is its URL? I want to get that info programatically, as an anonymous user.

For example:

- checking https://android-review.googlesource.com/ should give me
  "2.7-rc2-637-g76c7890"
- https://gerrit.chromium.org -- "2.5.4"
- https://git.eclipse.org/r/#/ -- "2.6.1"
- and so on

Ideally, I would like to be able to recognize ancient versions like 2.1.x as well.